# Put a relative link button in Rails Action Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, actiontext

In .html.erb `<%= link_to 'the listing', "years/1846", class: "btn btn-primary" %>` works. How can I put this in an Action Text field and have it be a link?

It will be hard coded to a specific record as shown. `years` is a table, model, etc in my app. Doesn't have to be a Bootstrap button, but does need to look like a link, so will need to be styled.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the raw html output of your link_to code directly to the ActionText field and it should work. Something like roster.description += ‘the listing’ etc (obviously roster and description are placeholder names for the ActiveRecord object and the ActionText field name)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not understanding your suggestion. The ActionText is the docs/_form.html.erb and the field name is content. So `doc.content += <a href "/years/1846">the listing</a>' which is still rendered literally. It can't be entered into the link helper that Rails Action Text provides because that has to start with `http`.

Comment: hmm, I'm sorry but I guess I'm not clear on what the desired output is, then. why not just manually enter the html link like this, then: `<a href='http://yourdomain.com/years/1846>the listing</a>` ?

Comment: That would probably work except during development, I am adding data during development on `localhost:3000`.

Comment: True.... One workaround would be to create a helper method that uses gsub and Rails.env to dynamically decide which server to display in the view.

Comment: Thank you. Even if I knew how to do it might be more complication. But maybe I'll look into it. Or maybe create another field with the info needed. Or maybe some other way